# query to show results if the value matches only single value

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Table**

```
| EMAIL | Checkout |
| --- | --- |
| abc@gmail.com | 2b |
| abc@gmail.com | 2c |
| fc@yahoo.com | 2b |
| red@reddit.com | 2c |
```

**I want to know how exactly I can query emails which has checkout primarily as 2b**

**Query I tried**

```
select distinct(email) from table where checkout='2b' and checkout<>'2c'
```

**The output I am getting**

```
| EMAIL | Checkout |
| --- | --- |
| abc@gmail.com | 2b |
| fc@yahoo.com | 2b |
```

**Desired output**

```
| EMAIL | Checkout |
| --- | --- |
| fc@yahoo.com | 2b |
```

Comment: Do you mean that the email for checkout='2c' must be equal to those for checkout='2b' strictly? Or the row for checkout='2c' may not exist?

Comment: Which database are you using?, MySQL and Snowflake are rather different.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.EMAIL
FROM YOUR_TABLE AS T
GROUP BY T.EMAIL
HAVING MIN(Checkout)='2b' AND MAX(Checkout)='2b'
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for

```sql
SELECT [DISTINCT] email
FROM table t1
WHERE checkout = '2b'
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM table t2 
                   WHERE t1.email <> t2.email
                     AND t2.checkout = '2c' )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how correct this is.

I only tested it with the given data
What I do here is bring everything that has 2b in and then
I exclude all the emails that don't have 2b.

so the following query will first create a list with all the emails with checkout 2B

- abc@gmail.com 2b
- fc@yahoo.com  2b

and after that. it will look again in your list and find checkouts without 2B

- abc@gmail.com 2c
- red@reddit.com 2c

and combine that 2 list together to get

- fc@yahoo.com  2b

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c96c6f7d0a73b298ee8bf12224b68315

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

### Snowflake Answers:

One way todo it is to use QUALIFY, to stripout rows that have a DISCTINCT COUNT of `checkout`s that is not equal to 1 AND that the checkout is not `'2b'`

```
SELECT email, checkout
FROM VALUES
    ('abc@gmail.com','2b'),
    ('abc@gmail.com','2c'),
    ('fc@yahoo.com','2b'),
    ('red@reddit.com','2c')
    t(email, checkout)
QUALIFY count(distinct checkout) over (partition by email)=1 AND checkout='2b';
```

| EMAIL | CHECKOUT |
| --- | --- |
| fc@yahoo.com | 2b |

but that can give many duplicate rows, as can been seen with this input:

```
SELECT email, checkout
FROM VALUES
    ('abc@gmail.com','2b'),
    ('abc@gmail.com','2c'),
    ('fc@yahoo.com','2b'),
    ('fc@yahoo.com','2b'),
    ('fd@yahoo.com','2b'),
    ('red@reddit.com','2c')
    t(email, checkout)
QUALIFY count(distinct checkout) over (partition by email)=1 AND checkout='2b';
```

| EMAIL | CHECKOUT |
| --- | --- |
| fc@yahoo.com | 2b |
| fc@yahoo.com | 2b |
| fd@yahoo.com | 2b |

So this can be worked around by pushed the COUNT into the SELECT and then using HAVING as the filter.

```
SELECT email, checkout 
FROM (
    SELECT email, any_value(checkout) as checkout, count(distinct checkout) as cc
    FROM VALUES
        ('abc@gmail.com','2b'),
        ('abc@gmail.com','2c'),
        ('fc@yahoo.com','2b'),
        ('fc@yahoo.com','2b'),
        ('fd@yahoo.com','2b'),
        ('red@reddit.com','2c')
        t(email, checkout)
    GROUP BY 1
    HAVING cc = 1
) 
WHERE checkout = '2b';
```

| EMAIL | CHECKOUT |
| --- | --- |
| fc@yahoo.com | 2b |
| fd@yahoo.com | 2b |

OR the use of DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT email, checkout
FROM VALUES
    ('abc@gmail.com','2b'),
    ('abc@gmail.com','2c'),
    ('fc@yahoo.com','2b'),
    ('fc@yahoo.com','2b'),
    ('fd@yahoo.com','2b'),
    ('red@reddit.com','2c')
    t(email, checkout)
QUALIFY count(distinct checkout) over (partition by email) = 1 and checkout = '2b';
```

| EMAIL | CHECKOUT |
| --- | --- |
| fc@yahoo.com | 2b |
| fd@yahoo.com | 2b |

### MySQL:

This should be valid sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT email, checkout FROM (
    SELECT  email, checkout, count(distinct checkout) over (partition by email) as cc
    FROM table_name
)
WHERE cc = 1 and checkout = '2b';
```